# How can I check if an input contains whitespaces or apostrphes in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

What is the best way to check if the value of an input contains a whitespace or an apostrophe.

Thanks.

Edit:

I've tried this

```
var r = new RegExp("[^\s\']+");
if (r.test($("#UserName").val())){
  alert("wrong");
}
```

But the alert appears even if I enter a string without whitespace and apostrphe.

Comment: I can't find the right regex, I've tried this
var r = new RegExp("[^\s\']+") but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you [edit] that into your question? code in comments is nearly illegible. What happened when you used that regex? What inputs did it work on? Which inputs did it fail on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RegExp is nearly correct:

```
var r = /[^\s\']+/
```

must be written

```
var r = new RegExp("[^\\s\\']+")
```

to escape the backslash in the string. But still, this checks for the existence of one or more characters beeing no whitespaces/apostrophes. I guess you want

```
var contains = !!string.match(/\s|'/); // boolean
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how can I make the test on my input with the contains variable ?

Comment: use `document.getElementById("UserName").value` as `string` and `contains` in your if-condition?